# Should I type everything in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

For example, I have a function:

```js
functiom sum(a: number, b: number) { return a + b }
```

In the above function should I annotate the function's return type is `number`? Because I think both the developer and compiler can infer the function's result must be `number` type.

Also like `httpClient.get` method in Angular return `Observable` type, it already defined in its signature, should I explicitly declare it in my proxy consumer function?

```js
function getPosts() {
  return this.httpClient.get();
}
```

So my question is should I type everything? If not, when should I type it.

Comment: Of course you shouldn't because TS is smart. In some cases he determine types by itself. And in simple cases you can not determine types. 
But if your function accepts and returns complex types, then it's best to define them. First of all for your colleagues.

Comment: The closer mistake to the type declaration: the easier it is to fix it. If you after refactoring accidentally change the `return` expression so that it returns different type - the type check error will be triggered several layers deeper on the first caller whose expectations you have broken (if any). Hence my practice: always type all functions explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a programming language that has both type inference and explicit manifest type annotations, you can think of the explicit manifest type annotations as the equivalent of *double-entry bookkeeping* in accounting: when you do everything right, it should never be needed, because the inferred type and the explicit type are always the same, *but* when you make a mistake, it helps you catch that mistake.

A good rule of thumb is:

> Every *public* interface should be explicitly annotated.

Whether or not you annotate private interfaces is your choice.

Personally, I have a slightly more relaxed version:

> Every *public* interface should be explicitly annotated, unless the type is blindingly obvious both from the *name* and the *implementation*.

So, for something like

```js
export function toString() { return "Dummy user"; }
```

I feel it is okay to leave out the type annotation, but others disagree.

In your first example, it is probably fine to leave out the type annotation. Although in a language that overloads `+` for both addition and string concatenation, it is easy to accidentally write code that returns a string when you meant to return a number, so it might make sense to protect against that.

In your second example, I feel it should have a type annotation. Remember my personal rule:

> Every *public* interface should be explicitly annotated, unless the type is blindingly obvious both from the *name* and the *implementation*.

I feel that the fact that a function named `getPosts` does not actually, you know, get the posts, but rather gets an `Observable` of posts is not sufficiently obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should make it a habit to explicitly set all types, it's will prevent having unexpected values and also good for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You should always type every function. And parameters in that function, too. The same is true for dto. Bugs will be found faster and readability is also better. It is the point of typescript after all.

And what about variables? Well, if the variable is totally obvious like this:

```
const x:string = "somestring";
const y:boolean = true;
```

Then you can skip it. It is unnecessary and some IDE-s even underline it. But it is not bad to give type to such variable. But if the variable is hard to understand, then, once again, type it.

In the end, it is not a bad idea to type everything. With obvious variables, you just lose your time, in my opinion. Maybe it is for discussion with a team you are working with.